# Black screen after resume (ATI radeon 6320)

Tags: ati, suspend

I buy acer aspire 4250 yesterday. It has ATI Radeon 6320 graphics card. I installed latest graphics driver from ati site. Graphics and other facilities are just working nice. Problem is it does not wake up from sleep. After suspend screen goes black. Power led is on but screen is black. How to debug or solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I see same named post in askubuntu but no is related to my problem. So i create a new post. Sorry for that

Comment: What drivers did you install and how did you install them?

Comment: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide   I installed from here first. After restart unity 2d was opened. Then i installed restricted driver from jocky (fglrx) without uninstall previously installed driver. After restart graphics looks good with unity 3D.

Comment: You need to use only 1 method to install the drivers, remove all drivers in your system and re-install using only the method on the wiki.cchtml.com page, no need to run jokey after specially if you did not remove the previous driver package.

Comment: in wiki method driver is not working. It broke unity 3d. If i use only jokey then unity 3D works but slow performance and  a AMD watermark show in desktop. I  applied all method to remove that watermark but did not work. Only above method (combine of 2 method) works. Only problem is suspense and resume.

Comment: Ok i found something. proprietary (Catalyst driver) does support older ubuntu ( <= 8.04) That's why it is not working in ubuntu 11.10. ATI driver does not support suspense when compiz is enable. It can be suspense after disable compiz. So now i have nothing to do unless don't use suspense facility.

Comment: I really got confused about all this, no mater as long as your happy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tips and problem solutions for the proprietary driver from AMD can you find in the unofficial wiki here: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu
There are some descriptions for problems with Suspend/Hibernation.